# TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, javascript-eventos

Bom dia, Preciso da vossa ajuda. Estou a receber dados vindo da porta serial "/dev/ttyUSB0", o meu objetivo" é de recuperar alguns informacoes ( temperatura e Humidade ) e substituir no objeto `enoceanRecords`.

```js
// Constants
const DEFAULT_SERIAL_PORT = "/dev/ttyUSB0";

// Dependancies
var fs = require('fs');
var vm = require('vm');
var events = require('events');
var cache = require('./plugins_cache.js');
var util = require('util');
var pk = require('node-enocean')();


// Type de données
var enoceanRecords = {
  Humidity: { 'value': '', 'type': 'TEXT', 'unit': '' },
  Temperature: { 'value': '', 'type': 'INTEGER', 'unit': 'A' }
 };
// Includes
vm.runInThisContext(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/" + "plugins_table.js"));
var table = new Table();

// Class
var PluginEnocean = function () {
    this.infos = { name: "enocean",
   version: "0.0.1"
   };
};

PluginEnocean.prototype.query = function () {
    return this.infos;
}

PluginEnocean.prototype.init = function (config) {
  var options = config.get('plugin:enocean');
    var path = DEFAULT_SERIAL_PORT;

    if(options !== undefined) {
        if(options['path'] !== undefined) {
            path = options['path'];
        }
    }

    // Open serial port
    console.log(path);
    pk.listen(path);
 
 // Set table name
    table.setName(this.infos['name']);
 
  // Collect data
    pk.on('data', function (data) {
   
   
   // =====================
   
   
   var temp = enoceanRecords['Temperature'];
   var humid = enoceanRecords['Humidity'] ;
   var valTemp = (data['values'])[1];
   var valHumid = (data['values'])[0];
   
   temp['value'] = valTemp['value'];
   temp['type']  = valTemp['type'];
   temp['unit']  = valTemp['unit'];
   
   humid['value'] = valHumid['value'];
   humid['type']  = valHumid['type'];
   humid['unit']  = valHumid['unit']; 
   
   //=====================
   
   var uuid = data['senderId'] ;
    
   for(key in enoceanRecords) {
     
   table.setRecord(key, enoceanRecords[key]);
   }
    
    
    
    
 // Feed data
   if(uuid !== undefined) { 
    table.setUuid(uuid);
    table.setRecord(key, enoceanRecords[key]);
    table.setStamp();
    cache.push(table);
   }
    });
  
 
};

PluginEnocean.prototype.run = function () {
};

PluginEnocean.prototype.exit = function () {
};

var enocean = module.exports = new PluginEnocean();
```

[image: Error image]

Comment: Bom dia, Preciso da vossa ajuda !! Estou a receber dados vindo da porta serial "/dev/ttyUSB0", o meu objetivo" é de recuperar alguns informacoes ( temperatura e Humidade ) e substituir no objeto "enoceanRecords" !!

Comment: Qual é a linha onde está a dar esse erro?

Comment: @Miguel  o  erro esta nessas duas linhas                                                    var valTemp = (data['values']);                                                                  var valHumid = (data['values'])[0];

Comment: Na linha anterior ao erro faça um `console.log(data['values']);` e veja o que imprime na consola, eu acho que isso não está a receber os valores como deveria

Comment: @Miguel o programa esta a funcionar 100% quando testo na consola firefox por exemplo, so nao funciona no "nodejs"... O comportamento nao é o mesmo no "nodejs" à que se deve isso ?!

Comment: Você põe o node a correr pelo terminal? Veja o que imprime lá

Comment: @Miguel, bem como dizia outrora, o Script corre muito bem fora do "nodejs" mas quando chamo : "sudo nodejs ScriptColletioDedonnes.js " ça marche pas ! ( nao funciona )

Comment: Ok, era só para saber o que `data['values']` armazena, desconfio que quando o chama sudo nod ela não vai ter o valor/valores que está a pensar

Comment: @Miguel esse é + ou - o formato do data que recebo : ` data = { loadFromBuffer: [Function],
  senderId: '018a75ba',
  raw: '0088860a',
  sensor:
   { id: '018a75ba',
     eep: 'a5-04-01',
     manufacturer: 'ENOCEAN_GMBH',
     title: 'New Temperature and Humidity Sensor',
     desc: 'I\'m a new sensor...',
     eepFunc: 'Temperature and Humidity Sensor',
     eepType: 'Range 0°C to +40°C and 0% to 100%',
     last: [ [Object], [Object] ] },
  values:
   [ { type: 'humidity', unit: '%rF', value: 54.400000000000006 },
     { type: 'temperature', unit: '°C', value: 21.44 } ] };`

Comment: Creio que já percebi o erro amigo. pagando nisso que mostrou => dados para o 1º obj do array `data['values']`:  `data.values[0].type = "humidity"`,  `data.values[0].value = 54.400`, `data.values[0].unit = "%rF"`

Comment: @Miguel qual é o erro mano? Exclareça melhor mano ?

Comment: Se o que está está a ser armazenado em `data` for isso que me mostrou, então estava a aceder mal aos valores que queria

Comment: @Miguel qual seria o proceder correto ? Merci !!

Comment: Mas de facto parece-me que é isso que está a fazer no seu código. Aqui tem: https://jsfiddle.net/9d23pqrb/ . Agora o importante é saber se `data` tem mesmo os dados nesse formato que me mostrou

Comment: @Miguel muito obrigado, cabei de constatar que os dados nao estao a vir no formato que estava supondo ! Vou dar uma olhada depois darei um sinal ! ... Tenha uma boa tarde @ Miguel... Merci Beaucoup !

Comment: Oi @Miguel mais uma vez passei pra agradecer, acabei de resolver o problema... A logica estava certa, o erro estava no "formato" do dado !! GRATO GRATO e mais uma vez GRATO !

Comment: Nada. Ainda bem que resolveu

Comment: @Tiago na paz mano !